# QGIS GPS not editing offline database

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, gps

I have a set of layers from PostGIS that I have converted to offline. I am attempting to edit them via GPS.

If the layer is point data, then I can add in that data without issue. However when I go to edit a polygon or line, it will not allow be to add a feature based on GPS location.

The geometry i'm using is MultiLine and MultiPolygon - I am about to try and edit this, but is there anything else causing issue here?

Secondly - QGIS docs say I can convert a WFS to offline - however whenever I try to convert my WFS (served through GeoServer) it just crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The GPS data format does not know polygon features (only points and lines), so you will not be able to import and edit them.

I suggest to use a shapefile format or spatialite database for off-Postgis-use.